# Runtime.getRuntime() inside JSP and security

Tags: shell, jsp, security, unix

From a JSP, I need to call a shell Unix.

To do that I tried the following code as an example :

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <body>
  <%
    try {
      Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
      Process exec = runtime.exec(new String[]{"/path/to/shell/myshell.sh", "param1", "param2"});
      int i = exec.waitFor();
      System.out.println(i);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  %>
  hi
  </body>  
</html>
```

All is ok, my shell is correctly called by the JSP, and the JSP got in return the correct value.

Although the code is executed on the server side, is it a problem for security to call shell Unix from JSP ? Are there any prerequisites about it ?

Comment: If it is insecure depends. Are `param1` and `param2`constant? If yes it is secure. If the parameters are values received via JSP or "user influenced" in a way this may lead to a security problem.

Comment: No param1 & param2 are not constant. They are built by the JSP depending from a value return by the user's browser.

Comment: I am not an Linux shell-script expert, but passing user-values as parameter is IMHO very risky (risk of arbitrary command execution). May be you can change the shell script to retrieve the values via stdin? AFAIK this should be secure.

Comment: @gduh so you are passing attacker controlled variables to Runtime.exec()? I don't understand why this important information was removed from your question.  The code snip provided is 100% unexploitable,  the comment you made is 100% terrifying.